# Get a limited, text-only excerpt from a WordPress post?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, foreach

I'm using "The Loop" in my own theme template to get the last three posts from WordPress.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <!-- DATE -->
    <div class="date">
    <?php the_time('m F Y');?>
    </div>

    <!-- TITLE -->
    <div class="title">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- SNIPPET -->
    <div class="content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Everything is working fine - except `the_excerpt()`. I need about 15-20 words of plain text from the post to show as a preview, instead of the full excerpt or the entire post content body. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using something like this to grab the first 20 words of the post if there is no excerpt available.

```
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Sorry this is to grab the characters not words I wasnt thinking clearly, if you wanted words here's a function on how to do it [here](http://www.nutt.net/2004/12/29/php-a-function-to-return-the-first-n-words-from-a-string/)

Answer (score 32):

### Why avoid using PHP's `substr()`

`substr()` truncates based on character count, NOT whole words, and the last word would most likely be truncated. It could also truncate the end HTML tag(s) and return malformed HTML, screwing up the rest of your layout.

### Don't re-invent the wheel!

WordPress 3.3 onwards has a [new core function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/) called `wp_trim_words()`

#### Parameter breakdown:

```
wp_trim_words($text, $num_words, $more);


$text
    (string) (required) Text to trim
    Default: None

$num_words
    (integer) (optional) Number of words
    Default: 55

$more
    (string) (optional) What to append if $text needs to be trimmed.
    Default: '…'
```

#### Example usages:

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30, '...'); ?>

<?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 50, '... read more &gt;'); ?>
```

Comment: excellent! this is "the WordPress way" to do it.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

Post contains images :

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>',']]&gt;', $content);
echo substr(strip_tags($content),0,100);
```

and without images:

```
 $content = get_the_content();
 echo substr($content, 0, 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
  return 20;}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

And just call this function from your template page or index.php file

```
the_excerpt();
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it if you want to modify the excerpt length everywhere one the site, but it sounds like the OP wants to only do it in one place.